# access arguments object in returned inner function

Tags: javascript

In the following function, I return a function.  This returned function tries to access 'arguments', but for some reason that references the outer function's 'arguments', not its own arguments.  I know this is because it is an arrow function, so bound to the outer function, but don't feel satisfied that this is a good enough understanding. Could you explain why and also how to access the inner functions 'arguments'

```
function add() {
  let pa = arguments;
  if(arguments.length>1){
    return "regular function"
  }else{
    return ()=>{
      return "curried function with " + pa + " and " + arguments;
    }
  }
}
```

I know that returning a named hoisted function fixes this:

```
function add() {
  let pa = arguments;
  if(arguments.length>1){
    return "regular function"
  }else{
    return function curried(){
      return "curried function with " + pa + " and " + arguments;
    }
  }
}
```

I would still like a clearer way of thinking about the arrow function, and how to access local arguments in the arrow function.

Comment: Arrow functions do not have their own `arguments`. Either use a full-fledged `function`, like you're considering, or use argument rest syntax: `return (...args) => {` and then `args` will be an array containing the arguments for that function. Personally, I'd avoid using `arguments` when not necessary (it rarely is, rest syntax is nicer)

Comment: thank you.  How did you know that arrow functions don't have 'arguments'?

Comment: You can look at the first answer in the linked question, or MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: also @CertainPerformance, I don't think this is a duplicate to the question you marked.  If someone was having this issue, they wouldn't know that that question is what they needed.

Comment: Sure it is a duplicate - look at the first answer on the canonical question. See the `However, ES2015 introduces an alternative to using arguments: the rest parameter....` part

Comment: my point is that if someone had my issue, they wouldn't know to read that question and look closely at that first answer.